# Angular dataTables with Ajax Source

Tags: angular-datatables

I'm trying to load data from an ajax source into angular datatable but it's not even hitting the ajax call.

```js
var analyzer=angular.module('analyzer', ['datatables']);
analyzer.controller('WithAjaxCtrl', WithAjaxCtrl);

            function WithAjaxCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
                    var vm = this;

                    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('/analyzer/List')

                    $scope.dtColumns = [
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('BuildName').withTitle('Name'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Total').withTitle('Total'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Passed').withTitle('Passed'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Failed').withTitle('Failed')

                ];
            }
```

Here's the html code for the table-

```html
<div ng-controller="WithAjaxCtrl">
     <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
</div>
```

data from ajax source is in the form -

```json
{"responseCode":0,"responseData":[{"Name":"Rob","Total":6273,"Passed":5874,"Failed":399}]}
```

So will i have to define the datasrc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to specify the `dataSrc` since your rows is contained in `responseData`, not in the default or expected `data` property. In angular dataTables there is an option setter named `withDataProp()` :

```js
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('/analyzer/List')
  .withDataProp('responseData')
```

Cannot link directly but look at **https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/api**